# C++: avoid optimizing out variable

Tags: c++

I have some useful code in constructor or class `Valuable`. I want be sure it's executed before `submain`. How can I guarantee that it's not optimized out?

```
int main()
{
    // Dear compiler, please don't optimize ctor call out!
    Valuable var;

    return submain();
}
```

Is local variable enough? Do I need to use `static`:

```
static Valuable *v = new Valuable();
delete v;
v = NULL;
```

Can I shorten previous to one liner:

```
delete new Valuable();
```

Comment: Make it `volatile`. Or should I even suggest that..?

Comment: If your constructor has side effects, then it will not be optimized out, unless it is a copy constructor, which is not the case here.  If your constructor doesn't have side effects, then you won't be able to tell if it's optimized out or not, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tried volatile?

Comment: I don't think it will be optimized out.  What compiler are you using?  Maybe you can look at the generated assembly code and determine if the constructor is still there.

Comment: @0x499602D2: How do you make a constructor volatile? I don't think you can do that

Comment: @0A0D I meant the variable though I guess I'm wrong in saying that too.

Comment: @0x499602D2: No, you're not wrong.  Making it volatile will ensure that it is not optimized out *even if* the constructor has no side effects.

Comment: Details on the question of when the constructor call may be optimized away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287010/c-calling-a-constructor-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: If ctor doesn't have side effect's but destructor does, it can't be optimized out too, right?

Comment: @demi: Correct, essentially.

Comment: @demi: Optimizations aren't allowed to make your program wrong or every compiler's full optimization flag would just treat your program as `int main(){}`. Unless you have evidence of the compiler screwing your program up, you shouldn't be worrying about things you don't even know are a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your constructor or destructor has observable behavior, the compiler is **not allowed** to optimize it out.  So there's no need to do anything tricky.

Comment: What if side effects are in destructor? Actually this 3rd party class initializes static mutex in destructor, that's why it's here.

Comment: It seems useful to be careful about the use of the word "side effects" (as opposed to "observable behaviour") in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8287110/777186

Comment: @demi: No, the compiler also not allowed to optimize out the object in that case as well.  The compiler must ensure that the program behaves identically to the abstract state machine specified by the C++ language standard.  The only time that the standard allows constructors to be elided is in two *very specific* situations involving copy constructors (returning a non-volatile automatic object from a function and copying certain unbound temporary objects); see C++03 §12.8/15.

Comment: So, to be very specific, mutex init in ctor and/or dtor will not be optimized out, right? That is observable behavior?

Comment: @demi: Yes, those have observable behavior, since they call into external library functions (e.g. `pthread_mutex_init()` on POSIX systems), which the compiler doesn't know anything about since their implementations haven't been linked in yet at the time of compilation.  So, it must assume that they have observable behavior.  If they were instead macros which had no body, then the compiler might optimize it out, since doing nothing has no observable behavior.