# How can I know when a temporary object is being created and destructed?

Tags: c++, oop

How can I find out when a temp object is being created and destructed and how?

For an example lets say we have a class named `Foo`
and a function that return a `Foo` object, and its parameters are an object, and a reference to an object.

```
Foo func(Foo a ,Foo & b);
```

How many objects are created with me knowing it? 
Is it created using copy constructor or regular?

Comment: Are you talking about memory allocations with `new` or instantiations of a class?  You could always make a custom `auto_ptr` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the constructor and destructor, insert a print statement into them.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){}
        Foo(const Foo &other) {std::cout<<"A copy was made\n";}
        Foo(Foo &&other) {std::cout<<"Foo was moved\n";}
        ~Foo(){std::cout<<"Destroyed Foo\n";}
};


Foo func(Foo a, Foo &b)
{
    return a;
}

Foo func_const(const Foo &a, Foo &b)
{
    return a;
}

Foo func_temp()
{
    return Foo();
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    func(f, f);

    std::cout<<"\n\n\n";

    func_const(f, f);

    std::cout<<"\n\n\n";

    Foo g = func_temp();
}
```

The above prints (using ideone):

```
Foo constructed
A copy was made
Foo was moved
Destroyed Foo
Destroyed Foo



A copy was made
Destroyed Foo



Destroyed Foo
Destroyed Foo
```

With the function signature:

`Foo func(Foo a, Foo &b)`,  parameter `a` may make a copy. The copy may also be elided by the compiler's optimisation. Parameter `b` never makes a copy as it is pass by reference and that usually says that you will be modifying the object passed; not modifying a copy.

When returning a Foo, it may or may not return a copy. It depends on the definition of your class. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: Adding print statements to anotherwise empty constructor may very well influence when and under what circumstances that constructor is called (and when and under what circumstances objects are created, too): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8287110/777186

Comment: @jogojapan The compiler is allowed to perform optimizations bypassing the creation of objects, even if the constructor has side-effects.

Comment: @bolov but the compiler is also allowed to elide copies when copy elision is not permissible as long as it follow the as-if rule. Adding the print statements changes that.

Comment: Yes. You guys are right. I removed the `std::cout` from the constructor and the construction of a foo was completely removed. This only happened for `func_temp` though. The other functions were unaffected.